# Magento 2 get product collection by price range

Tags: collections, magento2

How can I create a production collection based on pricerange in Magento 2.
This is what i have so far:

```
<?php namespace Qxs\Related\Block;

class Related extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
      //var_dump($this->currentProduct());
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['from' => 0, 'to' => 1000])
          ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
          ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
          ->setPageSize(5);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function currentProduct()
    {
      return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    }
}
?>
```

However, the code does not return a result including a price range. The result is totally empty but should return some products, how can I filter on price-range?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range filters, to me work in this way, with addFieldToFilter. Have you tried it?

```
$orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter( 'created_at' , array('from' => $dateFrom, 'to' => $dateTo) )
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc' );
            ->setPageSize(200);
```

Comment: ->addFieldToFilter('special_price', ['from' => 0, 'to' => 1000]) does not work.

Comment: That is strange, I tried with some products and it works for me, with normal price, like this    `$products = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addFieldToFilter( 'price' , array('from' => 0, 'to' => 5) )
   ->setPageSize(5);`

Comment: You are right, the status and visibility filters prevented the range from showing.

Comment: Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Actually not, I have not tried yet these types of filters, just found this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80179/magento-2-apply-visibility-and-status-filters-on-product-collection and it comes into my mind that maybe they are not well initialized. I cannot see their declaration as class properties... have you checked the returned values?

Comment: I just realized that they are configurable products, could that be an issue. It must be good because it works with visibility filters and price range separately but not together.

Comment: Mmm... could it be concerned to the visibility of configurable children? maybe some of them are not visible individually... dunno, something like that...